# Finding the remainder of the division of $\sum_{i=0}^{102} i^6+i$ by 4 and by 5

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I reasoned it this way: divisibility by 4 has 4 congruence classes. Only two of these are such that $a^6 + a \equiv 2 \pmod 4$; the others have no remainder. In $\sum_{i=0}^{102} i^6+i$ there are 52 summands that belong to the first two classes. So $52.2 = 104 \equiv 0 \pmod 4$. Hence, the first remainder is 0.

Mutatis mutandis for the remainder of the division by 5, which according to my calculations is 3.

Am I too off the mark here?

Comment: I haven't checked the details for $5$, but the reasoning looks quite correct.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: $\!\bmod 4$ the sequence $i^6+i$ has period $4$ with cycles $\,0,2,2,0\,$ whose sum $\equiv 0\pmod {4}$ so the total sum reduces to the sum of the final partial cycle $\, i = 100\,$ to $102$ which is $\,0 + 2 + 2\equiv 0.\ $ Same for modulus $5\ \ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $5$, the way I did it is as follows:

Note that $i^5\equiv i\mod 5$ (by Fermat's little theorem). So, $i^6+i\equiv i^2+i\mod 5$. So, your sum is congruent to $$\sum_{i=1}^{102} i^2+i=\frac{(102)(103)(205)}{6}+\frac{(102)(103)}{2}\equiv 0+3\equiv 3\mod 5.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine. Indeed:
$$\begin{align}i&\equiv0,1,2,3 \pmod{4}\\
i^2&\equiv0,1,0,1 \pmod{4}\\
i^6&\equiv0,1,0,1 \pmod{4}\\
i^6+i&\equiv0,2,2,0 \pmod{4}\end{align}\\
4i-3\le 102 \Rightarrow i\le 26.25 \Rightarrow i=26\\
4i-2\le 102 \Rightarrow i\le 26 \Rightarrow i=26\\
(26+26)\cdot 2=104 \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$$
Similarly:
$$\begin{align}i&\equiv0,1,2,3,4 \pmod{5}\\
i^2&\equiv 0,1,-1,-1,1 \pmod{5}\\
i^6&\equiv 0,1,-1,-1,1 \pmod{5}\\
i^6+i&\equiv 0,2,1,2,0 \pmod{5}\end{align}\\
5i-4\le 102 \Rightarrow i\le 21.2 \Rightarrow i=21\\
5i-3\le 102 \Rightarrow i\le 21 \Rightarrow i=21\\
5i-2\le 102 \Rightarrow i\le 20.8 \Rightarrow i=20\\
(21+20)\cdot 2+21\cdot 1=103 \equiv 3 \pmod{5}$$
Alternatively, for mod $4$:
$$i^6+i=\underbrace{i(i+1)}_{0\pmod 2}(i^4-i^3+i^2-i+1)\Rightarrow \\
i^4-i^3+i^2-i+1=\underbrace{(i-1)(i^3+i)}_{0\pmod{2}}+1 \Rightarrow \\
\sum_{i=0}^{102} 1 \equiv 0\pmod{2}.$$